# Pass arguments to function exactly as-is

Tags: bash, quoting, function, arguments

I have the following function:

```
bar() { echo $1:$2; }
```

I am calling this function from *another* function, `foo`. `foo` itself is called as follows:

```
foo "This is" a test
```

I want to get the following output:

```
This is:a
```

That is, the arguments that `bar` receives should be the same tokens that I pass into `foo`.

How does `foo` need to be implemented in order to achieve this? I’ve tried the following two implementations, but neither works:

- `foo() { bar $*; }`

  – output: `this:is`
- `foo() { bar "$*"; }`

  – output: `this is a test:`

My question is effectively how I can preserve the quoting of arguments. Is this possible at all?

Comment: Related: [How do I use a Bash variable (string) containing quotes in a command?](https://superuser.com/q/360966/11574)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `"$@"`:

```
$ bar() { echo "$1:$2"; }
$ foo() { bar "$@"; }
$ foo "This is" a test
This is:a
```

`"$@"` and `"$*"` have special meanings:

- `"$@"` expands to multiple words without performing expansions for the words (like `"$1" "$2" ...`).
- `"$*"` joins positional parameters with the first character in IFS (or space if IFS is unset or nothing if IFS is empty).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn’t aware that `$*` had this semantic – now it’s logical. I think this answer actually solves another problem I’ve been having when iterating over arrays …

Answer (score 6):

You must use `$@`, instead of `$*`

```
bar() { echo "$1:$2"; }

foo() { bar "$@"; }

foo "This is" a test
```

ouput

```
This is:a
```

Why does it work?

Because with `$*`, all parameter is seen as a **single word**, it mean that you will pass `This is a test` to `bar` function. In this case, the 1st parameter pass to function bar is `This`, 2nd is `is`.

With `$@`, each parameter is a **quoted string**, it mean that you will pass `'This is'` `'a'` `'test'` to `bar` funtion. So the 1st parameter pass to function bar is `This is`, 2nd is `a`.