# pass arguments to function as is

Tags: bash

Went through this post: [Pass arguments to function exactly as-is](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78470/pass-arguments-to-function-exactly-as-is)

But have a slightly different setup:

I have 3 bash functions foo, bar, baz. They are setup as follows:

```
foo() {
  bar $1
}

bar() {
  var1=$1
  var2=$2
  echo "$var1" test "$var2"
}
export ENV_VAR_1="1"
export ENV_VAR_2="2 3"

foo "${ENV_VAR_1} ${ENV_VAR_2}"
```

I'd expect the output to be:

```
1 test 2 3
```

But the output is:

```
1 test 2
```

I get why this happened. bar was executed as follows:

```
bar 1 2 3
```

My question is: how do I get it to execute

```
bar 1 "2 3"
```

Approaches I tried:

```
foo () {bar "$1"} 
# Out: 1 2 3 test. Makes sense since "1 2 3" is interpreted as a single argument.
```

Comment: The last line `foo () {bar "$1"}` is a syntax error.  If you want a one-line function definition, you need `foo() { bar "$1";}`  Note the space and the semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This provides a single string as an argument to `foo`:

```
foo "${ENV_VAR_1} ${ENV_VAR_2}"
```

Because `$1` is not in quotes, the shell performs word splitting and, consequently, this provides three arguments to `bar`:

```
bar $1
```

Word splitting is done on any IFS characters in `S1`.  The original source of those characters is not considered.

#### Simpler example

Let's define `x` as:

```
$ x="${ENV_VAR_1} ${ENV_VAR_2}"
```

Now, let's print `"$x"`:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "$x"
1 2 3
```

As you can see, `"$x"` is interpreted as one argument.  By contrast, consider:

```
$ printf "%s\n" $x
1
2
3
```

In the above, word-splitting is performed on `$x` creating three arguments.

Shell strings have no notion of history.  String `x` has no record of `2 3` being part of one string before `x` was assigned. String `x` just consists of `1`, space, `2`, space, and `3` and word splitting operates on the spaces.

#### Alternative: selecting your own IFS

This produces the output that you want:

```
$ foo() ( IFS=@;  bar $1; )
$ foo "${ENV_VAR_1}@${ENV_VAR_2}"
1 test 2 3
```

In `foo`, we set `IFS` to `@`.  Consequently, all subsequent word splitting is performed using `@` as the word separator.  So, when calling `foo`, we put a `@` at any location at which we want word splitting.

Comment: I understand now why it's happening. But I'm wondering if there's any way around it. Adding escaped quotes to the input sequence doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @user2103008   I added code showing how to get the string to split where you want it to.  Adding escaped quotes will not help unless `eval` is used and an unnecessary use of `eval` can lead to a variety of surprising problems.

Comment: I agree. I ended up refactoring so that I don't have to use space separated arguments within the argument string. I'll still accept the answer you gave since it makes sense.

Comment: Why would you stuff `${ENV_VAR_1}` and `${ENV_VAR_2}` together? That's the root of the problem. Keep them separate!

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a single argument to the function `foo`, which is the 5-character string `1 2 3`. The three digits are separated by spaces. `foo` has no reason to treat those spaces differently.

In combining `${ENV_VAR_1}` and `${ENV_VAR_2}` inside a single string, you've lost information. Recovering lost information requires magic, and computers can't do magic. To retain the separation between `1 2` and `3`, you need to change the way `foo` is called. Pass two separate arguments.

```
foo "${ENV_VAR_1}" "${ENV_VAR_2}"
```

Then all you need to do is [fix the quoting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) in the call to `bar`. Either pass on the two parameters:

```
foo () {
  bar "$1" "$2"
}
```

or pass on the whole parameter list:

```
foo () {
  bar "$@"
}
```